# Secure system against malicous limewire

Tags: macos, security

I want to install limewire on a mac os x 10.6.2 system. How I can secure my system through internal configurations against limewire threats like virus infections, shared folders etc.

Is there a way to let limewire run in somekind of sandbox, or some best practices on dealing with such software in mac os x?

Answer (score 1):

You can install [an anti-virus](http://www.iantivirus.com/), or run it in a virtual machine. [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) can run in seamless mode too, so it integrates into your workspace fairly unobtrusively.